# NOLOCK in Hive and Impala

Tags: mysql, hive, google-bigquery, acid, nolock

I want to understand why we don't use the NOLOCK keyword at the end SQL queries that run in Impala, Hive or MySQL. For example, I use both Hive and Impala through the Cloudera workbench at work. Cloudera workbench does not recognise the NOLOCK keyword. Similarly, I have used MySQL before as well. Even there, NOLOCK wouldn't work. Why don't we need to use NOLOCK with Hive, Impala, MySQL or Big Query?

Disclaimer: I want to clarify that I have a decent understanding of the NOLOCK feature and its use cases. This question is related to SQL flavours that do not require NOLOCK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's clarify what is [NOLOCK](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-impact-clr-strict-security-configuration-setting-sql-server-2017/). NOLOCK table hint allows to override default transaction isolation level(READ COMMITTED). `NOLOCK = READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level, that allows the query to see the data changes before committing the transaction which is changing the data.

[Hive does not support such isolation level](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-WhatisACIDandwhyshouldyouuseit?) (`READ UNCOMMITTED`) even in transaction mode. Oracle also does not support `READ UNCOMMITTED`, so no need in `NOLOCK` hint in these databases.

In Hive you can [turn off concurrency](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.support.concurrency).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does that mean Hive and Oracle only read committed data? If true, where does the uncommitted data go?

Comment: @Excel-lit the fact that they do not support it does not mean that they  have similar architecture. Hive does not support rollback and commit ( all are autocommitted). It can fail or succeed, snapshot isolation is supported. In Oracle the uncommitted changes are applied to the data and redo log is used to support isolation and recovery https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/onlineredo001.htm

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63378038/2700344

Answer (score 0):

Further to @leftjoin:

At this time only snapshot level isolation is supported.  When a given query starts it will be provided with a consistent snapshot of the data.  There is no support for dirty read, read committed, repeatable read, or serializable.  With the introduction of BEGIN the intention is to support snapshot isolation for the duration of transaction rather than just a single query.  Other isolation levels may be added depending on user requests.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Configuration